# Xtrabackup fails for full backup after a restore

Tags: percona, innobackupex

After a restore in Percona 5.7 from another Percona 5.7 server full backups are failing with the following error:

> xtrabackup: cd to /data/mysql
>       xtrabackup: open files limit requested 0, set to 819200
>       xtrabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
>       xtrabackup:   innodb_data_home_dir = .
>       xtrabackup:   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
>       xtrabackup:   innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
>       xtrabackup:   innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
>       xtrabackup:   innodb_log_file_size = 20971520
>       xtrabackup: using O_DIRECT
>       InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

```
InnoDB: Invalid redo log header checksum.
```

MySQL service is running in a master-slave replication and I don't see any error in logs regarding corruption or anything else.
I still don't get it since innodb_log_file_size = 20971520 match with size on disk:

```
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql   20971520 Apr 17 10:33 ib_logfile0
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql   20971520 Apr 17 10:33 ib_logfile1
```

Comment: You might need to share the my.cnf files for more help, for example, what are the settings of the innodb_log_checksums in each of them.

Comment: My innodb parameters from my.cnf:       innodb_buffer_pool_size = 21474836480
        innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
        innodb_log_file_size = 20971520
        innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
        innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
      innodb_buffer_pool_size = 21474836480
        innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
        innodb_log_file_size = 20971520
        innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
        innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
        innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
        innodb_io_capacity=600
        innodb_io_capacity_max=1000

Comment: Not much to go on. Can you paste the entire output of both the backup and restore? Use pastebin or similar.